# Selenium Mozilla does not accept cookies

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website and up until last week it used to work fine but now it's showing me an error because the browser does not have cookies enabled. Is there any way to overcome this?

These are my headers:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("start-maximized");
options.add_argument("enable-automation");
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox");
options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars"); 
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
```

and this is the error. It's in chinese though:

> UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
> Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: 您的浏览器限制了第三方Cookie，这将影响您正常登录，您可以更改浏览器的隐私设置，解除限制后重试。

Comment: Why do you think it's because the browser does not have cookies enabled? The error doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: The chinese part says: "Your browser restricts third-party cookies, which will affect your normal login. You can change the privacy settings of your browser, and try again after lifting the restriction."